# How to bold part of string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oraclereports

I want to bold the part of string from query output in Oracle 10g. For example
if I query

```
select 'Oracle'||'10g' from dual`
```

my desired output is following:

Oracle**10g**

Please help! Thanx in advance.

Comment: Where is this being displayed?

Comment: SQL is only providing data, creating a view that you like is the responsibility of your application.

Comment: It has nothing to do with SQL and DATABASE.

Comment: @DanBracuk it will displayed in the filed of Oracle Report i use Oracle report builder 6i.

Answer (score 3):

The following example query will enclose '10g' in `<b>` html tag. Then you will also need to set the 'Contains HTML tags' property of the desired field to 'Yes' in its property palette, in Reports Builder 6i.

```
SELECT 'Oracle ' ||'<b>' || '10g' ||'</b>' FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: i already done your mentioned above method but when i run my report its show null(empty) field.

Comment: does it display data when you remove the html [b] tag?

Comment: Then you can create two fields on report and fetch data as two separate columns. One field on the report will be formatted as bold.